# Create-react-app is running in dev build but blank screen in production build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node-modules, create-react-app, production-environment

I don't understand why this is happening! All good in local dev while I was working on the application. but after production build shows just a blank screen.

my App.js file

```
import React from "react";
import "react-perfect-scrollbar/dist/css/styles.css"
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css"
import "react-image-lightbox/style.css"
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
import "react-modern-calendar-datepicker/lib/DatePicker.css";
import "./App.css"
import Routes from "./routes";
import {ToastContainer} from "react-toastify";


const App = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <ToastContainer autoClose={3000}/>
            <Routes/>
        </>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Here is my index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

In my package.json:

```
"homepage": "."
```

[image: This is the only error is showing on my console.]

Can anyone help how can I fix this?

Comment: how did you build production build , i mean command you used to build ?

Comment: how are you testing your production build?

Comment: @Codenewbie `npm run build` 
@PraveenNambiar deploying static file into server